# Keypath error with Core Data SUBQUERY and NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Apologies if this is a duplicate, 20 minutes of searching didn't yield this exact situation or a solution.

I have a Core Data stack with three classes `XClass`, `YClass`, and `ZClass`. `XClass` has a one-to-many relationship with `YClass`. `YClass` has a one-to-many relationship with `ZClass`.

Using an instance of `NSFetchedResultsController`, I'm trying to fetch all instances of `XClass` for which at least 1 `YClass` has at least 1 `ZClass`.

My predicate is defined as follows:

```
// ...stuff
NSFetchRequest * fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];

NSEntityDescription * entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([XClass class])
                                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

fetchRequest.predicate = 
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"0 < SUBQUERY(yObjects, $y, $y.zObjects.@count > 0).@count"];

// ..instantiate NSFetchedResultsController and perform fetch
```

This causes a fatal exception with the message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed to handle $y.zObjects.@count'`

Elsewhere, I've successfully fetched `YObject` instances with the predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"zObjects.@count > 0"];`

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong? Thank you much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that NSPredicate objects violently when you use collection operators in the predicate string for the SUBQUERY.  It also appears that you cannot operate on a collection in the subquery predicate.  That is unless the variable represents a collection in the predicate.

BAD: `SUBQUERY(yObjects, $y, $y.zObjects == NIL) > 0`

OK: `SUBQUERY(yObjects, $y, SUBQUERY($y.zObjects, $z, $z == NIL) > 0) > 0`

The following expression will add all non-nil objects to the filtered collection returned by the SUBQUERY.  In other words, the returned collection will contain all instances of XClass with instantiations of ZClass.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yObjects.@count > 0 AND (SUBQUERY(yObjects, $y, (SUBQUERY($y.zObjects, $z, $z != NIL).@count > 0)).count > 0)"];
```